# Running a linear regression on multiple files in R

Tags: r

I have a folder with 20 text files from several instrument runs. The data section all have the same format like this

```
22/05/11;   16:03:28;       0.000;   6.079;   31.41;   84881;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:29;       0.017;   6.063;   31.44;   84868;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:30;       0.034;   6.079;   31.41;   84868;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:31;       0.051;   6.079;   31.41;   84868;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:32;       0.068;   6.068;   31.43;   84868;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:33;       0.085;   6.068;   31.43;   84881;   25.60; E0;
22/05/11;   16:03:34;       0.102;   6.079;   31.41;   84874;   25.60; E0;
```

What I would like to do is read in every file within my folder, run a linear regression, and pull out the slope and R2 value.

As of now, this is my code for doing this for a single file.

```
O2=read.table("Coral 1_Dark.txt",skip=58, sep=";",header=FALSE)
names(O2)<-c("Date","Time","Log_Time","O2_mgL","Phase","Amp","Temp C","Error Message")
O2$id<-seq_len(nrow(O2)) #creates unique ID for each measurement (use for regression)
attach(O2)
fit=lm(O2_mgL~id)
summary(fit)
```

After running this code, I have been manually entering the slope and R2 data.

For now I can create a variable that contains all the files I am interested in with

```
F=list.files()
```

Which gives me all 20 files

```
[1] "Coral 1_Dark.txt"   "Coral 1_Light.txt"  "Coral 10_Dark.txt"  "Coral 10_Light.txt" "Coral   2_Dark.txt"  
[6] "Coral 2_Light.txt"  "Coral 3_Dark.txt"   "Coral 3_Light.txt"  "Coral 4_Dark.txt"   "Coral  4_Light.txt" 
[11] "Coral 5_Dark.txt"   "Coral 5_Light.txt"  "Coral 6_Dark.txt"   "Coral 6_Light.txt"  "Coral 7_Dark.txt"  
[16] "Coral 7_Light.txt"  "Coral 8_Dark.txt"   "Coral 8_Light.txt"  "Coral 9_Dark.txt"   "Coral 9_Light.txt"
```

And what I would like to end up with would be something like this for all 20 files

```
Coral            Slope        R2
Coral 1_Dark      0.23         98.3
Coral 2_Dark      0.33         99.3
```

ect

Any suggestions? I've never worked with any of the apply functions or any kind of loop- but I'm thinking this is about to change.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
wd <- "C:/Data"
files    <- dir(wd)
varnames <- c("Date", "Time", "Log_Time", "O2_mgL", "Phase", "Amp", "Temp C",
            "Error Message")
results  <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  fname <- paste(wd, files[i], sep="/")
  data <- read.table(fname, sep=";", skip=58)
  colnames(data) <- varnames
  data$id <- 1:nrow(data)
  fit <- summary(lm(O2_mgL~id, data=data))
  results[i,1] <- fit$coefficients[2]
  results[i,2] <- fit$r.squared
}

rownames(results) <- sub(".txt", "", files)
colnames(results) <- c("Slope", "R2")

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code might have a chance. It's not a good idea to use attach but especially so when you are creating functions.

```
Coral_1_Dark.txt <- "22/05/11;   16:03:28;       0.000;   6.079;   31.41;   84881;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:29;       0.017;   6.063;   31.44;   84868;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:30;       0.034;   6.079;   31.41;   84868;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:31;       0.051;   6.079;   31.41;   84868;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:32;       0.068;   6.068;   31.43;   84868;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:33;       0.085;   6.068;   31.43;   84881;   25.60; E0;
+ 22/05/11;   16:03:34;       0.102;   6.079;   31.41;   84874;   25.60; E0;

list_of_summaries <- sapply( 'Coral_1_Dark.txt', function(nam) { 
    O2 <- read.table(file=textConnection(get(nam)), sep=";",header=FALSE)
    names(O2) <- c("Date","Time","Log_Time","O2_mgL","Phase", 
                               "Amp","Temp C","Error Message", "junk")
    O2$id <- seq_len( nrow(O2) )
    fit=lm(O2_mgL~id , data=O2)
    summ <- summary(fit) 
    return( c(slope= coef(fit)["id"], R2= summ[["r.squared"]] ) )  })

as.data.frame( list_of_summaries )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried using it and got a                "Error: unexpected ']'in:
"    summ <- summary(fit) 
    return( c(slope= summ[["coefficients"]]["id"]]" error. I tried moving some of the [ around, but no help there. Any idea what could be the problem. Sorry for not including a full data set to check this on.

Comment: I edited with a test case that exposed some flaws which I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are about to get an introduction to the apply functions. Basically do a `dir()` call on the folder then wrap everything you've done in a function with a single file argument. and return the results your interested in.  Then call lapply on the file list with the function as the second argument